# react-select debounced async call not displaying suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) loading the results from an api and debouncing the queries with [lodash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/lib/Async';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
import {search} from './api';

const _loadSuggestions = (query, callback) => {
  return search(query)
    .then(resp => callback(resp));
};

const loadSuggestions = debounce(_loadSuggestions, 300);

function SearchboxTest() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const onChange = value => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      value={inputValue}
      loadOptions={loadSuggestions}
      placeholder="text"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}
```

It seems to work fine when I enter something in the searchbox for the first time (query is debounced and suggestions populated correctly), but if I try to enter a new value, a second fetch query is fired as expected, but the suggestions coming from that second call are not displayed (and I don't get the "Loading..." message that react-select displays).

When I don't debounce the call the problem seems to go away (for the first and any subsequent calls):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/lib/Async';
import {search} from '../../api';

const loadSuggestions = (query, callback) => {
  return search(query)
    .then(resp => callback(resp));
};

function SearchboxTest() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const onChange = value => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      value={inputValue}
      loadOptions={loadSuggestions}
      placeholder="text"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Any idea what is going on? Any help to understand this issue would be much appreciated.

M;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Select Async loadOptions is not loading options properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984105/react-select-async-loadoptions-is-not-loading-options-properly)

Answer (score 31):

I was aslo facing the same issue and got this solution.

> If you are using **callback function**, then You **DON'T** need to **return** the
> result from API.

Try removing **return** keyword from **_loadSuggestions** function.
as shown below

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
 import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/lib/Async';
 import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
 import {search} from './api';
 
 const _loadSuggestions = (query, callback) => {
   search(query)
     .then(resp => callback(resp));
 };
 
 const loadSuggestions = debounce(_loadSuggestions, 300);
 
 function SearchboxTest() {
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
 
   const onChange = value => {
     setInputValue(value);
   };
 
   return (
     <AsyncSelect
       value={inputValue}
       loadOptions={loadSuggestions}
       placeholder="text"
       onChange={onChange}
     />
   )
 }
```

Comment: Had the same issue and this is the correct answer, and should be flagged as so!

Comment: This answer worked well for us. 
If you want to keep the functions inside the function component use 

import { useMemo } from 'react';

function SearchboxTest() {
  const loadSuggestions = useMemo(
    () => debounce(_loadSuggestions, 300)
  , []);
 ... 

https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/

Answer (score 8):

For all of you people still struggling with this and don't want to install lodash only for debounce function like I do, here's my solution

debounce function

```
export default function debounce(fn, delay = 250) {
    let timeout;

    return (...args) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            fn(...args);
        }, delay);
    };
}
```

debounce implementation

```
const loadOptionsDebounced = useCallback(
    debounce((inputValue: string, callback: (options: any) => void) => {
        fetchOptions(inputValue).then(options => callback(options))
    }, 500),
    []
);
```

fetchOptions() is my async fetch function that returns array of options

Answer (score 6):

Use [react-select-async-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-async-paginate) package - This is a wrapper on top of  `react-select` that supports pagination. Check it's [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-async-paginate)

React-select-async-paginate works effectively with internal denounce. You can pass debounce interval in the props.

```
<AsyncPaginate
  value={value}
  loadOptions={loadOptions}
  debounceTimeout={300}
  onChange={setValue}
/>
```

Here is [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y2xq39v5k)

Comment: examples of code and more explanation would be useful here.

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki Please check updates answer, added example. --Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone.

```
freeze = false //mark delay 
timer //saved timer

loadAddress = async (strSearch: string) => {
   this.freeze = true //set mark for stop calls
   return new Promise(async (res, err) => { //return promise 
   let p = new Promise((res, err) => {
     if(this.freeze) clearTimeout(this.timer) //remove  prev timer 
     this.timer = setTimeout(async () => {
        this.freeze = false
        const r = await this.load(strSearch)//request
        res(r);
     }, 2000)
  })

  p.then(function (x) {
     console.log('log-- ', x);
     res(x);
  })
});
};
```

Comment: This answer saves my day.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was, instead of making use of the default debounce from lodash, making use of the [debounce-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce-promise) package:

```js
import React from 'react';
import debounce from 'debounce-promise';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

const debounceFunc = debounce(async () => {
    return [] // SelectOptions
}, 200);

export function MyComponent() {
  return <AsyncSelect loadOptions={debounceFunc} defaultOptions />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution help me following.
I have AsyncSelect where i want data from https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch. My provider is:

```js
const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider({
    params: {
        countrycodes: "cz",
        limit: 5
    }
});
```

const `provider` you will see below one more time.

```js
<AsyncSelect className="map-search__container"
                         classNamePrefix="map-search"
                         name="search"
                         cacheOptions
                         components={{DropdownIndicator, IndicatorSeparator, Control, NoOptionsMessage, LoadingMessage}}
                         getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                         getOptionValue={getOptionValue}
                         loadOptions={getData}
                         onChange={handleChange}
                         isClearable
                         placeholder={inputSave || ""}
                         value=""
                         inputValue={input}
                         onMenuClose={handleMenuClose}
                         onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                         onFocus={handleFocus}
                         blurInputOnSelect
                         defaultOptions={true}
                         key={JSON.stringify(prevInputValue)}
            />
```

`cachceOptions` - is basic
`components` - my components
`loadOptions` - is the most important!
anything else is not important

```js
const getData = (inputValue: string, callback: any) => {
        debouncedLoadOptions(inputValue, callback);
    }
```

```js
const debouncedLoadOptions = useDebouncedCallback(fetchData, 750);
```

```js
import {useDebouncedCallback} from 'use-debounce';
```

This use was my key for solution. I tried debounce from lodash, but i had still problem with not working debouncing. This use help me and did my problem solve.

```js
const fetchData = (inputValue: string, callback: any) => {
        return new Promise((resolve: any) => {
            resolve(provider.search({query: inputValue || prevInputValue}));
        }).then((json) => {
            callback(json);
        });
    };
```

`prevInputValue` is props from parent... (you don't need it)
Callbacks was second key. First was useDebouncedCallback.

#sorryForMyEnglish