# Async React Select component how to change the argument of the loadOptions function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-async

I have a react async select component. This component has a `loadOptions` props, where you need to pass a function to load data. At the moment it looks like this

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [positionId, setPositionId] = useEffect('');

  return (
    {
      positionId &&
      <AsyncSelect
        loadOptions={(search, prevOptions, additional) => loadMyOptions(search, prevOptions, additional, positionId)}
          (...other props)
        />
    }

      <Input
      value={positionId}
      onChange={(e) => setPositionId(e.target.value)}
      />
  )
}
```

The `loadMyOptions` function describes the data loading logic. This function takes the last parameter, `positionId`, which changes depending on what was entered in the input field. Now if you enter a value in the input field, then `AsyncSelect` appears and it loads the necessary options. But if after that you enter something else in input and change the `positionId`, and try to load new data into `AsyncSelect`, then it doesn't send a request to the backend with the new `positionId` value.

I tried to wrap the function in `useCallback`

```
const loadNewOptions = useCallback(
  (search, prevOptions, additional) => {
    return loadMyOptions(search, prevOptions, additional, positionId);
  },
  [positionId]
);
```

But it did not help. Please tell me how to make it so that when changing `positionId` and clicking on `AsyncSelect`, a request with a new value of `positionId` goes to the backend?

Comment: Can you give the link of the react async select lib that you are using? there's a lot of them.

Comment: Yes sure https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-async-paginate

Comment: Would the example explained here solve your issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984105/react-select-async-loadoptions-is-not-loading-options-properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's a race condition somewhere in your code, but you don't have to use the "outer" positionId, instead use the one that you pass instead:

```
    const loadNewOptions = useCallback((search, prevOptions, additional, posId) => {
      return loadMyOptions(search, prevOptions, additional, posId)
    }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried it but it didn't work. If you try to do like here

https://codepen.io/NailG/pen/oNGdayN

Then to the backend goes to the value positionId = undefined.

Also I tried this option

https://codepen.io/NailG/pen/bGoMmKr

Then to the backend goes to the value positionId = "" (empty string). It takes the positionId value which is specified by default in setstate

Comment: I also noticed that if you manually delete all values from the input and enter a new value, then when the value is erased and positionId === "" is an empty string, then AsyncSelect is removed from the page and after a new value is entered, then the loadNewOptions function works correctly

Comment: But I need the actual positionId argument to be substituted into the function for loading data